# Ionic livereload insecure origin error for getUserMedia()

Tags: android, ionic-framework, https, webrtc, livereload

I am developing WebRTC app on Android with Ionic v1 framework.
When I run the app on Android device with "ionic cordova run" command, it works without an error. However, when I run it with livereload(ionic cordova run -c -l) for debug, I get the following error.

getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

I understand that livereload points to the development PC with http, so the insecure origins error occurs.

I searched in the internet and stackoverflow for the error, and I found some solutions, but all solutions were for ionic serve using a browser, not for Android device with livereload.

I have been struggling the problem for a couple of weeks, and I have not been able to resolve it. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you found anything? I've got the same problem.